# Calling child component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So im trying to call a function from child component, but all I do ends up with an error. I've been searching for more than hour and found many solutions, but most of them are either outdated or I'm doing something wrong.

Here's my parent component and theres simple getData function in child component named Query.

```
const ref = useRef();
return(
     <Query ref={ref} />
     <button onClick={() => ref.current.getData()}>dasfas</button>
)
```

I also tried forwardRef hook, but I couldn't call it anyway.

Comment: You should call the method like this:
ref.current.getData()

Comment: You have made a reference to an HTML element, I don't see which element has a getData() method.

Comment: @Deda the reference doesn't points to an html element but to a custom react component instance

Comment: @MuhammedB.Aydemir I've got that error after change: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined

Comment: Do you get the error when you click the button or on render?

Comment: @MuhammedB.Aydemir when I click the button

Comment: That's weird, can u share the code of your child component?

Comment: Sure here it is: https://pastebin.com/CuQPLdVu
There will be more functionality later, but first I just wanted to console.log the values to see if it work. BTW if in this function is always true when I click the button @MuhammedB.Aydemir

Comment: why don't you put the button inside ```Query```?

Comment: I had the button inside, but then I decided to move it outside this div, so it's located more friendly for user. @JuniusL.

Comment: then move the function to the parent component and pass the data to the component.

Comment: Yeah I'll propably have to if I don't find any solution using ref

Answer (score 0):

Move the function to the parent component and pass data to `Query` component as props.

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

const Query = ({ query }) => {

  return (
    <Grid container item sm={12}>
      <Grid item sm={12}>
        <Typography variant="h5">Queries</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sm={12}>
        <div id="sqlQuery" />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sm={12}>
        <div id="treeViewBefore" />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sm={12}>
        <div id="treeViewAfter" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Query;
```

Parent component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Parent = () => {
  const [sqlQuery, setSqlQuery] = useState("");

  const getData = async () => {
    if (global.answercreated) {
      var response = await fetch(
        `${global.serverURL}?type=before&&property=${global.token}`
      );
      var data = await response.text();
      const jsonbefore = JSON.parse(data.replace(/'/g, '"'));

      response = await fetch(
        `${global.serverURL}?type=after&&property=${global.token}`
      );
      data = await response.text();
      const jsonafter = JSON.parse(data.replace(/'/g, '"'));

      response = await fetch(
        `${global.serverURL}?type=sqlquery&&property=${global.token}`
      );
      data = await response.text();
      const sqlQuery = data;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Query query={sqlQuery} />
      <button onClick={() => getData()}>dasfas</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```